Rotary Encoder para una ESP32-WROOM-32D, driver L298N y un motor DC JGA25-370 – 12V /60RPM con Encoder
Quiero sacar la posición del encoder a la vez que me mueve la rueda que tengo conectada al motor hacia adelante y hacia atrás. Con lo que tengo, solo me saca la posición del encoder pero no gira el motor, y está comprobado que le llega corriente cuando está en el modo de adelante o atrás.
El código es el siguiente (para Arduino IDE):
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP32Encoder.h>

// Asignación de pines del ESP32
int motor2Pin0 = 27;
int motor2Pin1 = 26;
int enable2Pin = 14;

const int pwmChannel0 = 0;      // Canal 0 PWM
const int pwmChannel1 = 1;      // Canal 1 PWM
const int freq = 30000;  // Frecuencia PWM
const int resolution = 8;  // Resolución PWM en bits

// Definición de los pines para el encoder
#define PIN_IN1 18
#define PIN_IN2 19

// Crear un objeto ESP32Encoder
ESP32Encoder encoder;

int lastPos = 0;
unsigned long lastPrintTime = 0;
const unsigned long printInterval = 5000; // Intervalo de 5 segundos

void setup() {
  // Declaración de los pines como salidas
  pinMode(motor2Pin0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motor2Pin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(enable2Pin, OUTPUT);

  // Configurar las funcionalidades del PWM
  ledcAttachChannel(motor2Pin0, freq, resolution, pwmChannel0 ); 
  ledcAttachChannel(motor2Pin1, freq, resolution, pwmChannel1 ); 

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Initializing...");

  // Inicializar el encoder
  // ESP32Encoder::useInternalWeakPullResistors = true;
  encoder.attachSingleEdge(PIN_IN1, PIN_IN2);
  encoder.clearCount();
}

void loop() {
  // Leer la posición actual del encoder
  int newPos = encoder.getCount();

  // Imprimir la posición del encoder si ha cambiado o cada 5 segundos
  unsigned long currentTime = millis();
  if (newPos != lastPos || (currentTime - lastPrintTime) >= printInterval) {
    Serial.print("Encoder Position: ");
    Serial.println(newPos);
    lastPos = newPos;
    lastPrintTime = currentTime;
  }

  // Verificar entrada serial para controlar el motor
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    String command = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    command.trim();  // Elimina espacios en blanco al inicio y al final

    int speed = 0;
    String action;

    if (command.startsWith("FORWARD")) {
      speed = command.substring(8).toInt();
      action = "FORWARD";
    } else if (command.startsWith("BACKWARD")) {
      speed = command.substring(9).toInt();
      action = "BACKWARD";
    } else if (command == "STOP") {
      action = "STOP";
    } else {
      action = "INVALID";
    }

    switch (action.charAt(0)) {
      case 'F':  // FORWARD
        moveMotorForward(speed);
        break;
      case 'B':  // BACKWARD
        moveMotorBackward(speed);
        break;
      case 'S':  // STOP
        stopMotor();
        break;
      default:
        Serial.println("Invalid command");
        break;
    }
  }
  //delay(10);
}

void moveMotorForward(int speed) {
  int dutyCycle = map(speed, 0, 255, 0, 255);
  Serial.print("Moving Forward with speed: ");
  Serial.println(dutyCycle);
  digitalWrite(enable2Pin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
  ledcWrite(pwmChannel0, dutyCycle);  // Set the duty cycle to desired speed
  ledcWrite(pwmChannel1, 0);  // Set the duty cycle to desired speed
}

void moveMotorBackward(int speed) {
  int dutyCycle = map(speed, 0, 255, 0, 255);
  Serial.print("Moving Backwards with speed: ");
  Serial.println(dutyCycle);
  digitalWrite(enable2Pin, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, HIGH);
  ledcWrite(pwmChannel0, 0);  // Set the duty cycle to desired speed
  ledcWrite(pwmChannel1, dutyCycle);  // Set the duty cycle to desired speed
}

void stopMotor() {
  Serial.println("Motor stopped");
  digitalWrite(enable2Pin, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motor2Pin1, LOW);
  ledcWrite(pwmChannel0, 0);  // Set the duty cycle to desired speed
  ledcWrite(pwmChannel1, 0);  // Set the duty cycle to desired speed
}


Saca la posición del encoder pero no mueve el motor, está comprobado que le llega corriente y bien cableado. Llevo varias semanas intentando otros códigos pero no consigo resolverlo. Si alguien tiene alguna idea de esto y me pudiera ayudar, estaría realmente agradecido.
